# Capistrano Using Old Ruby Version

Tags: ruby, macos, capistrano

I'm trying to get Capistrano to work on my MacBook (OSX Mountain Lion) but am having a lot of difficulties. It started with it throwing an error:

```
cillosis:myapp macbook$ cap deploy
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sshkit-1.2.0/lib/sshkit.rb:32: undefined method `require_relative' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/all.rb:2
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/bin/cap:2
from /usr/bin/cap:19:in `load'
from /usr/bin/cap:19
```

It seemed I had Ruby 1.8 installed and it doesn't work correctly with Capistrano (found this Googling around).

So I installed Ruby 2.0 using rvm. RVM starting throwing a bunch of errors so I got rid of it using `rvm implode` and found that the 2.0 version was still on my computer. I checked my **$PATH** and the locations it pointed at contained the Ruby 1.8. So I renamed that to *ruby_old* and copied the new ruby to that folder (*/usr/bin*). Then when I did a `ruby -v` it came back as version 2.0. So I thought, great, now we can finally run Capistrano.

Just to be sure, I did a `gem update` which came back as having updated the **sshkit** gem which was throwing the error before. So I go to deploy, and get the same exact error as I started with.

I know the **deploy.rb** script is correct because I use it all the time on another Mac.

TL;DR; After some fumbling, when I type `ruby -v` it comes back as using version 2.0 but when I do a `cap deploy` with Capistrano, it tries to use version 1.8 of ruby. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dumb, but simple way out would be to completely remove RVM and both ruby versions, then install again from scratch. I would recommend 1.9.x over 2.0 due to some gems not being up to speed yet, but that's up to you.

Another option would be to specify the ruby version in your gemfile (as heroku does it), then do a "bundle exec cap deploy". Again, no guarantees - but it might force capistrano to behave the way you want until you find a proper solution.

Comment: You say "Gemfile" and I say huh? I'm not a ruby developer so am unfamiliar with a lot of the terminology. I primarily write in PHP and am only using Ruby because Capistrano requires it. Do you know why Capistrano is grabbing an old version? How many places does it install  itself?

Comment: Ah, understood. So you are trying to deploy a PHP application with capistrano? Why not, I guess...

The issue is most likely that the version of ruby installed on your machine is old (so I am assuming that you're using a mac, because they come with an old borked version).

I would definitely recommend an uninstall and reinstall of both ruby versions *and* RVM, then reinstalling RVM and installing Ruby 1.9.x through RVM. *Then* use capistrano to do your magic, and come back here with more questions.

Comment: I guess the issue with your suggestion is "uninstalling" ruby. Do I just delete the /Library/ruby folder? What about the versions sitting in /etc/bin or /etc/local/bin...and is there anything out there assuming Ruby is at one of these locations?